# unresolved names linking against library but passing obj files directly works fine?

Tags: c++, macos, ld

Consider the following g++ invocation (Apple GCC 4.2.1, running on OSX 10.6.5)  which works just fine:

```
g++ -c util/warthog_cfg.cpp -o  util/obj/warthog_cfg.o -DOS_MAC -O0 -Wall -Wno-sign-compare -ansi -fmessage-length=0 -m32
g++ main.cpp -o main -I./util util/obj/warthog_cfg.o -m32
```

Observe that I passed warthog_cfg.o (a required object file) as an argument in the second line. Now I want to put warthog_cfg.o into a library file and link against that. I run the following:

```
g++ -c util/warthog_cfg.cpp -o  util/obj/warthog_cfg.o -DOS_MAC -O0 -Wall -Wno-sign-compare -ansi -fmessage-length=0 -m32
ar -crs lib/libutil.a  util/obj/warthog_cfg.o
g++ main.cpp -o ./bin/main -DOS_MAC -O0 -Wall -Wno-sign-compare -ansi -fmessage-length=0 -m32 -L./lib -framework CoreServices -I./TransitC -I./cpd2012/ -I./util -lutil -lutil
Undefined symbols:
  "warthog::util::warthog_cfg::print(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)", referenced from:
      _main in ccI5ycWY.o
  "warthog::util::warthog_cfg::warthog_cfg()", referenced from:
      _main in ccI5ycWY.o
  "warthog::util::warthog_cfg::parse_args(int, char**)", referenced from:
      _main in ccI5ycWY.o
  "warthog::util::warthog_cfg::~warthog_cfg()", referenced from:
      _main in ccI5ycWY.o
      _main in ccI5ycWY.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [main] Error 1
```

The calls appear identical. I thought perhaps the problem is with ar not adding the .o file to the archive. However, otool seems to indicate otherwise. File sizes seem about right too.

```
otool -I lib/libutil.a 
Archive : lib/libutil.a
lib/libutil.a(warthog_cfg.o):

-rw-r--r--  1 foo  staff  5908 10 Sep 18:39 warthog_cfg.o
-rw-r--r--  1 foo  staff  6800 10 Sep 18:35 lib/libutil.a
```

What's going on here?

Comment: The option `-I` is used to add an include directory for the pre-processor to search, it doesn't include the referenced file when linking.

Comment: Joachim: notice I also add -L./lib which is where ar puts the library file containing my object file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not actually seeing you linking the library to the main program.

I don't generally use -L for this (this sets a search path, but I know where the library is). Just add your lib/libutil.a on the linker invocation just like you would another object file. If you want to keep the "search my lib" scheme, add -lutil and hope there's no other util library getting in the way.

Comment: Hi Christian, your suggestion works nicely. I just discovered however that the root cause of my problem is calling my archive libutil. There exists a system library by the same name in /usr/lib and that location was being searched before ./lib. I will accept your answer nonetheless however.

Comment: Yeah, while my names are unlikely to clash with other libraries, this is a good reason to not use the "search" feature of the linker if you are dealing with your own libraries. If you specify the actual path, you know that this will be used, even if there's another library with the same name